# How can I identify using Array proper/key name and then filter another object by that?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two sets of data. How can I loop and get the array property/key name to filter another object with it and merge them into a new array.

I tried using Map/filter/find but was unable to do it. In the data below, I want to search for 001(from 1st set) in the second set and then get data. Need to do this for all the data in set 1.

Data Set 1 :

```
{
    "001": {
        "hasCar": false,
        "hasBike": false
    },
    "002": {
        "hasCar": true,
        "hasBike": false
    },
    "003": {
        "hasCar": false,
        "hasBike": false
    },
    "004": {
        "hasCar": false,
        "hasBike": true
    }
}
```

Data Set 2 :

```
[
    {
        "UserNumber": "001",
        "vehicleDetails": {
            "country": "IN",
            "color": "Black",
            "company": "Ford",
            "postalCode": "XXXXXXX"
        }
    },
    {
        "UserNumber": "002",
        "vehicleDetails": {
            "country": "IN",
            "color": "Black",
            "company": "Ford",
            "postalCode": "XXXXXXX"
        }
    },
    {
        "UserNumber": "003",
        "vehicleDetails": {
            "country": "IN",
            "color": "Black",
            "company": "Ford",
            "postalCode": "XXXXXXX"
        }
    },
    {
        "UserNumber": "004",
        "vehicleDetails": {
            "country": "IN",
            "color": "Black",
            "company": "Ford",
            "postalCode": "XXXXXXX"
        }
    },
]
```

Desired Output :

```
{
    {
        "UserNumber": "001",
        "hasCar": false,
        "hasBike": false,
        "vehicleDetails": {
            "country": "IN",
            "color": "Black",
            "company": "Ford",
            "postalCode": "XXXXXXX"
        }
    },
    {
        "UserNumber": "002",
        "hasCar": false,
        "hasBike": true,
        "vehicleDetails": {
            "country": "IN",
            "color": "Black",
            "company": "Ford",
            "postalCode": "XXXXXXX"
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: *"I tried using Map/filter/find but was unable to do it"*: that should work. Please provide your code so we can see what is wrong with it.

Comment: _"Desired Output :"_ - please _explain_ the logic behind that - we shouldn't have to figure it out based solely on "I have, I want".

Comment: What happens if your object has a different number of entries than your array. Which is the number of results then? Is it determined by the array or by the plain object? Why does your example have a desired output of only two entries? What happened with "003" and "004"?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Object
  .keys(dataSet1)
  .map(k => Object.assign(dataSet1[k], dataSet2.find(d2 => d2.UserNumber === k)))
```

Explanation:

1. `Object.keys` returns the list of keys of the first dataset ["001", "002", ...]
2. For every element of this list finds the corresponding item in the second dataset using the `find` method.
3. Merge the result of find with the value of the corresponding object using `Object.assign`